# SQL beginner question : what is the principle to fill some sub-table from a main table?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm beginner in database knowledge.
I begin using cloud db2 lite service on Dallas db2 lite hosting.
I've already loaded the main table from a .csv file into my db2 lite instance.
This main table is filled, populated, by data (almost 40 columns and 40000 rows).
From this main table, I would like to fill in 3 empty sub-tables in which I've already define the fields (let say, columns, type, ...).
In my mind, I thought it will be possible to "connect" the sub-tables to the main table, in order to fill the sub-tables.
But, I've not understood if it is possible, or how it is possible.

I've tried `INSERT "INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ... ORDER BY"` SQL command type.
This type of SQL command fills the sub-tables. But in the way I did it, it only copies data from main table to sub-table. It does not link the sub-table to the already filled main table.

I've got the feeling I have not yet understand the principle to "pump" data from a large main table into sub-tables, or to fill sub-tables with data coming from the main table, connecting sub-tables to the main table.

Is there such a principle?

Comment: Would you be so kind to explain what you mean under "link the sub-table to the already filled main-table"

Comment: Mean in my beginner mind : the main table is filled. Sub-tables are empty. The goal is to fill the sub-tables, linking them constantly to the main table. Doing a INSERT INTO SELECT FROM GROUP BY does not make the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to "link" the subtable to the main table, then you probably don't want a table at all.  You want a view:

```
create view subtable as
    select . . .
    from . . .;
```

You can query the view just as you would any other table.  But the SQL engine runs definition code each time, so the data is always up-to-date.

Comment: Ok. I understand. And, if I want to get sub-tables and to fill them from the main table keeping them linked to the main table ? Is that a principle that match with sql and database practices ?

Comment: @anch . . . You have two options.  The simpler is a *materialized view*, which is a lot like a view except the data is actually stored in the database and the database keeps it up-to-date (perhaps on a schedule).  The second is to use triggers to maintain the consistency between the two tables.

Comment: ok, understand. Does SQL allows to launch query on views and "between" views, as for relationnal sub-tables ? Is it the same principle ?

Comment: @anch . . . For a `SELECT` query, views are used just like tables.